# OpenMp invalid controlling predicate for operator !=

Tags: c, gcc, openmp

I try to work with OpenMP in C, but found some problem with the `!=` operator and `parallel for`.
For the next code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () 
{
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7};
    int *p;
    int *stop = array + 7;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (p = array; p != stop; p++)
        printf("a: %d\n", *p);

    return 0;   
}
```

I get this error:

```
omp.c:10:18: error: invalid controlling predicate
    for (p = array; p != stop; p++)
                    ^
```

But when I replace the `!=` with `<`, it compiles and works great.
Is there any alternative? I want to paralleling a code with "stop" pointer, and have to use the `!=` operator for that.

Compiling command: `gcc -o omp.o -fopenmp example.c`

Thanks!

Comment: *Why* do you have to use `!=`? You can still have a "stop pointer" while using `<`. In fact it might even be better from a parallel point of view, since then there is no chance of a thread possibly using a pointer *beyond* `stop`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is just an example, I have a program that use `!=` and the pointer is not necessarily smaller. I want to keep the program as close to the original code, so I prefer keep it logic and stop conditions

Answer (score 4):

OpenMP specification requires that the loop be in the so-called  *canonical form*. Canonical form admits only four types of relational operations in the test clause of the `for` loop. Namely `<`, `<=`, `>`, or `>=`.

The full specification of the canonical form can be read directly from OpenMP specification:

```
for ( init-expr ; test-expr ; incr-expr ) structured-block
```

where `test-expr` is one of the following:

```
var relational-op b
b relational-op var
```

with `relational-op` being `<`, `<=`, `>`, or `>=`. It is Chapter 2.6 in the [OpenMP specification version 4.5](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf) (chapter numbers may change in future versions of the specification).

For the case in your example

```
for (p = array; p != stop; p++)
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
for (p = array; p < stop; p++)
```

For other cases you might have to modify your code to bring the loops into a canonical form.